# How can I get a value in the scope of loop and use it outside the loop in Python

Tags: python, for-loop

Can someone assist me in thinking my way through this problem. In the code below, I'm taking a list and opening all of the .log and .txt files, as to search them for a particular string. In the inner most for loop there is an if and else statement that determines if a string was found or not. I want to count the number of files that a string was matched in ..., and some kind of way pass that to the third(last) for loop and display ... (eg. Files Matched: 4). I'm still learning python, so I'm unaware of all the different constructs that would expedite this endeavor. I'm sure this is a straight forward problem, but I have exhausted everything I know to do besides rote trial and error. Thanks!

```
...

for afile in filelist:
    (head, filename) = os.path.split(afile)
    if afile.endswith(".log") or afile.endswith(".txt"):
        f=ftp.open(afile, 'r')
        for i, line in enumerate(f.readlines()):
            result = regex.search(line)
            if result:
                ln = str(i)
                pathname = os.path.join(afile)
                template = "\nLine: {0}\nFile: {1}\nString Type: {2}\n\n"
                output = template.format(ln, pathname, result.group())
                hold = output
                print output
                ftp.get(afile, 'c:\\Extracted\\' + filename)
                temp.write(output)
                break
        else:
            print "String Not Found in: " + os.path.join(afile)
            temp.write("\nString Not Found: " + os.path.join(afile))

        f.close()
for fnum in filelist:
    print "\nFiles Searched: ", len(filelist)
    print "Files Matched: ", count
    num = len(filelist)

    temp.write("\n\nFiles Searched: " + '%s\n' % (num))
    temp.write("Files Matched: ") # here is where I want to show the number of files matched
    break
```

Comment: I think either your formatting is off, or you've made a mistake.  It seems likely the `else` statement should be lined up with the `If result` - since it appears to be for when the regex doesn't match.

Comment: The `else` is supposed to be lined up with the `for`.  It will be entered if the `break` statement in the `for` loop is never executed, which would mean that the regex didn't match for any line in the file.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

How about this:

```
count = 0
for afile in filelist:
    (head, filename) = os.path.split(afile)
    if afile.endswith(".log") or afile.endswith(".txt"):
        f=ftp.open(afile, 'r')
        for i, line in enumerate(f.readlines()):
            result = regex.search(line)
            if result:
                count += 1
                ln = str(i)
                pathname = os.path.join(afile)
                template = "\nLine: {0}\nFile: {1}\nString Type: {2}\n\n"
                output = template.format(ln, pathname, result.group())
                hold = output
                print output
                ftp.get(afile, 'c:\\Extracted\\' + filename)
                temp.write(output)
                break
        else:
            print "String Not Found in: " + os.path.join(afile)
            temp.write("\nString Not Found: " + os.path.join(afile))

        f.close()
for fnum in filelist:
    print "\nFiles Searched: ", len(filelist)
    print "Files Matched: ", count
    num = len(filelist)

    temp.write("\n\nFiles Searched: " + '%s\n' % (num))
    temp.write("Files Matched: "+str(count)) # here is where I want to show the number of files matched
    break
```

count starts at 0 and increments for every file that there is a match for.

Comment: I think you mean `count += 1`.

Comment: @Gabriel - Thanks! I figured it was a straight forward fix, and even attempted the count +=1, but placed it in the wrong location.